# Problem loading cram_language in SLIME

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I have a problem. I set up cram_emacs_repl (because I'm a bit lazy :P). SLIME loads well but when I run the command (ros-load:load-system "cram_language" :cram_language) to use the package CPL, it says:

Component "cram_language" not found

I don't understand the problem. I have the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH configured correctly and ROS finds cram_language package with the command 'rospack find' but in SLIME doesn't.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11398/problem-loading-cram_language-in-slime/) by [biyonder](https://answers.ros.org/users/1155/biyonder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. However, I followed the steps at [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2047/why-rosmake-cram_pl-says-cause-fatal-errors) and when I do rosmake in roslisp_repl gives:

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['roslisp_repl']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/biyonder/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111006-075129
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['roslisp_repl'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['roslisp_repl']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

It seems there doesn't find roslisp_repl as package or stack. The path ~/cram-ros is correctly set in $PATH.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [biyonder](https://answers.ros.org/users/1155/biyonder/) with karma: 26 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-10-06**:
Did you try 'source ~/cram-ros/setup.bash' and then a 'roscd roslisp_repl'? If that works, 'rosmake roslisp_repl' should also work.